# Redis sorted sets

Tags: redis, convention, sortedset

I have a list of Ids from a table that I want to store in a Redis sorted set. Each of these ids has a date and entity associated with it. The plan is to use the id as the score and allow Redis to sort them accordingly. When it is time for lookup I will get the max id and the min id from the table by start and end dates. Using this min and max id I can get a list of ids between them using Redis' zrangebyscore command.

```
entities' values = zrangebyscore ids (min max
```

Since the ids are sorted numerically I can reliably get all the ids belonging to my entity between two dates(min id and max id).  My question is when creating my sorted set I do not know what to enter for the value in "key score value".

```
 zadd key score value
```

When I create the list I do not have any information that fits well for the "value" parameter. Can this be blank or some arbitrary id?

```
zadd ids 123 ???
```

I am still rather new to Redis and any info on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You do not need to _create_ a sorted set, you just add values with its score, the sorted set is created when you insert the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Sorted Sets, you just need a Set:
 1. define a key that is something like: `entity1:ids`
 2. add your ids to this key

Use `SADD entity1:ids 1` to add and `SMEMBERS` and `SUNION` to retrieve all the ids for one entity or the union of multiple entities, [doc here](https://redis.io/commands/sadd).